# Wordpress Register New User function giving errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `register_new_user($user_login, $user_email)` for registering users on my wordpress site. But its giving me error Like

> {"error":true,"message":{"errors":{"registerfail":["Missing security
>   token from submission."]},"error_data":[]}}

I have also used wp_nonce_field for security in my form.
Can someone help me to fix this error "**Missing security token from submission**."

Here is my HTML FORM 
`

```
<form id="registration_form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="POST">
<div class="form-field">
<span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e('Username', 'wp-ajax-login'); ?></span>
<input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_login" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Username', 'wp-ajax-login'); ?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-field">
<span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e('Email', 'wp-ajax-login'); ?></span>
<input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_email" id="pt_user_email" type="email" placeholder="<?php _e('Email', 'wp-ajax-login'); ?>" />
</div>

<div class="form-field">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="pt_register_member"/>
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" data-loading-text="<?php _e('Loading...', 'wp-ajax-login') ?>" type="submit"><?php _e('Sign up', 'wp-ajax-login'); ?></button>
</div>
<?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-register-nonce','user-register-security'); ?>
</form>
```

`AJAX CODE:`
      // Get variables

```
    $user_login = $_POST['pt_user_login'];  
    $user_email = $_POST['pt_user_email'];

    // Check CSRF token
    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-register-nonce', 'user-register-security', false) ){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
        die();
    }

    // Check if input variables are empty
    elseif( empty($user_login) || empty($user_email) ){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
        die();
    }

    $errors = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);  

    if( is_wp_error($errors) ){
      //Display errors
    }
```

`

Comment: can you show the code, what have you done yet.(esp the html for register form)

Comment: @Yamu please check , edited my question

Comment: can you post your ajax functions.php code?

Comment: @vel updated the question

Comment: have you applied the form on home page itself?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line in your ajax code

```
 if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-register-nonce', 'user-register-security', false) )
```

with

```
if( !check_ajax_referer( 'user-register-security', 'ajax-register-nonce', false) )
```

NOTE: The name of the action is the 2nd parameter instead of the first

Reference: [wp_nonce_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)

Comment: If you see my code I am not getting any error from check_ajax_referer function. I am getting error from register_new_user function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user_login = $_POST['pt_user_login'];  
$user_email = $_POST['pt_user_email'];

// Check CSRF token
if( !check_ajax_referer( 'user-register-security', 'ajax-register-nonce', false) ){
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
    die();
}

// Check if input variables are empty
elseif( empty($user_login) || empty($user_email) ){
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
    die();
}

$errors = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);  

if( is_wp_error($errors) ){
  //Display errors
}
```

**Example**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field

```
<form method="post">
   <!-- some inputs here ... -->
   <?php wp_nonce_field( 'name_of_my_action', 'name_of_nonce_field' ); ?>
</form>


<?php

if ( 
    ! isset( $_POST['name_of_nonce_field'] ) 
    || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_nonce_field'], 'name_of_my_action' ) 
) {

   print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
   exit;

} else {

   // process form data
}
```

Comment: I tested your code, not getting any error from check_ajax_referer function or nonce field. I am getting error from register_new_user function

Comment: above the code working form me. can you post ajax javascript also?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify nonce variable using wp_verify_nonce() method as well.

So following should be your if condition

```
if (wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['user-register-security'], 'ajax-register-nonce' ) ) {
        // valid nonce. 
        // other code.
}
else{
     // invalid nonce, do appropriate action.
}
```

Please let us know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found alternative to register_new_user() function. Here is the working code for new user registration:

```
    // Get variables
    $user_login = $_POST['pt_user_login'];  
    $user_email = $_POST['pt_user_email'];

    // Check CSRF token
    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-register-nonce', 'user-register-security', false) ){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
        die();
    }

    // Check if input variables are empty
    elseif( empty($user_login) || empty($user_email) ){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
        die();
    }


    if( null == email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
      // Generate the password and create the user
      $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
      $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $password, $user_email );

      // Set the nickname
      wp_update_user(
        array(
          'ID'          =>    $user_id,
          'nickname'    =>    $user_email
        )
      );

      // Set the role
      $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
      $user->set_role( 'contributor' );

      // Email the user
      //wp_mail( $user_email 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $password );
        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-success">'.__( 'Registration complete. Please check your e-mail.', 'wp-ajax-login').'</p>'));
            die();
    } // end if
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('This email already exists.Please use different email address.', 'wp-ajax-login').'</div>'));
        die();
    }
```

Thanks to all who replied to my question,I have tested your codes but there is no issue with wp_nonce or verify nonce value. I think issue was due to some plugin that uses registration_errors hook to add errors in it.